# Visual Studio Code keeps trying to use conda.exe while it has been uninstalled

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have uninstalled conda(Miniconda3) and VSCode, after which I installed python manually and reinstalled VSCode. However VSCode keeps trying to use conda.exe whenever I start the editor or run the debugger.

```
& : The term 'C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\Victor\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:4
+ (& "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" " ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\ProgramData\...ripts\conda.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This is the error I keep getting. I have checked my global settings.json and local settings.json to no avail. (Edit: conda.exe is not in my user Path or system PATH.)

[Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14hu5.png)
When I manually activate the new env I created for Django it works.

Kind regards,
Victor

Comment: Did you choose a new interpreter? (via bottom bar or the Command Palette → Python: Select Interpreter)

Comment: I have, I am using an env that has Django installed. When I manually run the code using the env it works. I added a picture to my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:
In my documents folder there was a folder called "WindowsPowerShell" that had the following code:

```
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

Removing this folder with file inside fixed the issue! I do not know how this got there. Conda must have done this somehow.

Comment: profile.ps1 was also in Documents/PowerShell folder

Answer (score 1):

Is it still in your Windows Environment Variables?

You can check that by going to: System info > Advances > Environment Variables

Next, check for user and system if it is present.
Check the variabel Path or PATH in the system box, click edit, and see whether it is in there or not. If so, remove Conda.exe from there.

Comment: Hi Richard, It is not in any of my paths. They do have the path to the current installation of python3.9.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`
2. Delete the file `profile.ps1`